# Replace SQL query parameter in a Excel power query

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, excel-2016

I have a workbook where I fetch data from SQL Server using fixed parameter values for a SQL query.

I want to make another sheet and have the parameter for the SQL query be taken from the cell values.

I didn't find anything on this regard.

Also I would like to refresh the data as soon as the cell values changes in the other sheet.

Comment: I had difficulty finding the answer to this same question when I was first looking for it, as well. I think it's generally more advised to, when possible, run the query for the data without the variable restrictions, and then limit the data once it's in PowerQuery. There have been times when I've gotten a warning from PQ about refreshing a query with this type of setup.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this to work, you need to set up three different parts:

1) A parameter table in an Excel sheet

2) Changes to the advanced editor in PowerQuery

3) A macro to refresh the PQ when any cells in the parameter table are changed

---

### **1) Excel Table**

You can see I included a column called `param` which *can* hold a Parameter name to help keep straight which parameter is which.

[image: Sample Param Table]

---

### **2) PQ Advanced Editor**

```
let
    ParamTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Param = "'" & Text.From(ParamTable[value]{0}) & "'",
    Source = Sql.Database("IP Address", "Database Name", [Query="Select * from weeks#(lf)where date >= '2018-01-01' and date < " &Param])
in
    Source
```

*Equivalent alternative:*  (Difference in location of variable used in SQL query.)

```
let
    ParamTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Param = "'" & Text.From(ParamTable[value]{0}) & "'",
    Source = Sql.Database("IP Address", "Database Name", [Query="Select * from weeks#(lf)where date < " &Param & " and date >= '2018-01-01'"])
in
    Source
```

*Alternative Variable Type:* (If dealing with numbers, the string markers `'` aren't required)

```
let
    ParamTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Param = Text.From(ParamTable[value]{0}),
    Source = Sql.Database("IP Address", "Database Name", [Query="Select * from weeks#(lf)where cnt < " &Param & " and date >= '2018-01-01'"])
in
    Source
```

**Explanation:**

After pulling the Parameter Table into the PQ Query (`ParamTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content]`), the columns can be accessed by column name `[value]` and the rows by a zero-index number `{0}`. Since I was pulling in a date-value. I needed to convert it to a string value I could insert into the SQL Query -- thus the `Text.From()` and the appended `'`'s to the ends (*SQL marks strings with single ' rather than the double "*)

Since I named the variable `Param`, to use it in the string, I substituted `&Param` for the value which had originally been there.

---

### **2.1 Power Query's Value.NativeQuery**

```
let
    ParamTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Param = ParamTable[value]{0},
    Source = Value.NativeQuery(Sql.Database("IP Address", "Database Name"), "Select * from weeks where date < @dateSel and date >= '2018-01-01'",[dateSel = Param])
in
    Source
```

*Alternative Formatting:*

```
let
    ParamTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Param = ParamTable[value]{0},
    Source = Sql.Database("IP Address", "Database Name"),
    Data = Value.NativeQuery(Source, "

Select * from weeks
where date < @dateSel and date >= '2018-01-01'

",[dateSel = Param])
in
    Source
```

**Notes:**

When using `Value.NativeQuery()`, you can pass a date or datetime value directly in as a variable without having to include the single apostrophes.

Sometimes splitting the data retrieval into a `Source` step and a `NativeQuery` step can help with PQ's sporadic firewall issues.

---

### **3) Macro**

This works for a simple check if anything in the table has changed, then runs the refresh. You will need to make sure this is placed in the correct module. Items you will need to change are:

- `Sheet1` is the codename of the worksheet with the parameter table.
- `"Table"` is the name of the Parameter table
- `"Query - Query1"` is the name of the connection to be refreshed

*Note:* `Query1` is the name of the query. Default names for connections are usually `Query -` & query name

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Query1").Refresh
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know how to get to the general query editor? Once there, go to the "View" tab, then you should see an "Advanced Editor" button second from the right. The button on the very right is the "Query Dependencies" button which is also semi-useful.

Comment: I'm getting a `cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation` error when I paste the power query in the advanced editor. Can you help?

Comment: I can try. Could you show me the code you have in your Advanced Editor? Also, just clarifying, that for Part 2), what I posted is really just an example of how it would look with the param line added, and the variable substitution in place.

Comment: Sure. `let
    Client_UID = "'" & Text.From(Table1[value]{0}) & "'",
    Year = "'" & Text.From(Table1[value]{1}) & "'",
    Period = "'" & Text.From(Table1[value]{2}) & "'",
    Source = Sql.Database("0.0.0.0", "TestDB", [Query="EXEC [sp_sprocname] @Client_UID = " &Client_UID & ", @Year = " &Year & ", @Period = " &Period & ", @Trans = '123'"])
in
    Source`

Comment: First, I just want to point out that of `@Year` is not supposed to be a SQL string (i.e. SQL is expecting an integer or double) you should change `Year = "'" & Text.From(Table1[value]{1}) & "'"` to `Year = Text.From(Table1[value]{1})`  Also, same with any other value SQL is not expecting a string for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168248/discussion-between-soham-dasgupta-and-mistella).